# Difference between Deps and Tracker in Meteor js

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

Is there any difference between Deps and Tracker in meteor ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Deps` was renamed to `Tracker` as part of [0.9.1](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v091). The name change is currently backward compatable, however you should start using `Tracker` going forward.